# Does primes in polynomial ring imply primes in the ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given a ring $A$ and the polynomial ring $A[x]$, I know that if $p \subset A$ is a prime ideal then $p[x]$ is a prime ideal in $A[x]$. What is not clear to me is:

> Suppose $(1) \neq a \subset A $ is an ideal and $a[x]$ is a prime ideal in $A[x]$. Does it follow that $a$ is a prime ideal in $A$ ? I also want to understand whether **ALL** prime ideals in $A[x]$ are of the form $p[x]$ for some prime ideal $p \subset A$.

Can I get some hints / ideas / suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $A[x]/a[x] = (A/a)[x]$, i.e. $a[x]$ is prime if and only if $(A/a)[x]$ is a domain, which is the case if and only if $A/a$ is a domain, which is equivalent to $a$ being prime. Hence your first statement is correct.

Your second statement is false. For instance the prime ideal $(2,x) \subset \mathbb Z[x]$ is not of that form.

It is also trivially false for polynomials over fields. $K$ has only one prime ideal, namely the zero ideal, but $K[x]$ has many prime ideals, at least $(x-\lambda)$ for any $\lambda \in K$.